# How does this embedded Python packaging find its lib files?

Tags: python, blender, python-embedding

Blender(*) for Windows is shipped with an embedded Python, like this:

```
blender-2.79b-windows64\
    2.79\
        python\
            bin\
                python.exe
                python35.dll    # only these 2 files
            lib\
                asyncio\
                collections\
                ... 
                + many .py and .pyd files
```

Launching `python.exe` works even if there is no system global Pyton install. Also, there is no `.pth` or `._pth` file anywhere.

**Question: how does `python.exe` know that the libs are in `..\lib`?**

Note (*): this is *not* specific to Blender (I used Blender just as an example), this is common for many software that ship Python embedded with them.

Comment: It's possible they built their own `python.exe`.  The default `lib` directory is one of the configuration parameters.

Comment: @TimRoberts Do you know where to find the configuration parameters they used to build the official "Windows embeddable package (64-bit)" in https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/? Is the build process of this package documented somewhere, to see what they set for the default `lib` configuration parameter?

Comment: I'm wondering why you care.  You can print `sys.path` to see what the initial path is.

Answer (score 2):

The 'lib' directory is the default directory here where Python finds all its stdlib modules. The directory name is basically a builtin default (which you could change by rebuilding with a different config). This is all extensively documented in
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#sys-path-init
and https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site.

The question seems to assume that there is something special about the way the embedded Pythons finds modules, compared to a regular, non-embeddable Python. But there is not. Quote from the offical docs about the embedded Python on Windows:

> As with the application use, packages can be installed to any location as there is an opportunity to specify search paths before initializing the interpreter. Otherwise, there is no fundamental differences between using the embedded distribution and a regular installation.

(https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#embedding-python)

Comment: This does not explain how Blender's `python.exe` knows it has to check in `../lib`  (and not in `lib`) to find the modules - where is this information stored?

Comment: I guess you didn't read documentation? It's builtin into the python.exe itself. 
Check:
```
os.path.listdir(sys.exec_prefix)
```
This can be defined when you build Python (CPython), see:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb66600558cb8d5dd9a56f562bd9531eb1e1685f/Doc/using/configure.rst

Comment: For the blender build/install as far as I could determine this is defined in
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/77b6f5d7e33848223313830a8d2c1fa3f47ed03b/scripts/site/sitecustomize.py#L14